# Datatable doesn't update data (knockout binding) on updating list even after destroying and initializing datatable again.

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, datatable, binding

I have an html file that contains a Datatable with an observable array binded to it. On click of a button the data in list gets updated but the datatable doesn't reflect new data. Even after removing body and destroying table it doesn't refresh table.

```
  <table id="SVRnew" class="display">
  <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>Domain</th>
     <th>Sub Domain</th>
     <th>Event Type</th>
     <th>Event Sub type</th>
     <th>Event Name</th>
     <th>SVR</th>
     <th>Deloitte Capability</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
     <tbody data-bind="foreach : $root.LISTSVREASnew">
      <tr>
          <td class="table-column-ellipses" data-bind="text:DOMAIN"></td>
          <td class="table-column-ellipses" data-bind="text:SUB_DOMAIN"></td>
          <td class="table-column-ellipses" data-bind="text:EVENT_TYPE"></td>
          <td class="table-column-ellipses" data-bind="text:EVENT_SUBTYPE"></td>         <td class="table-column-ellipses" data-bind="text:EVENT_NAME"></td>
          <td class="table-column-ellipses" data-bind="text:SVR"></td>
          <td class="table-column-ellipses" data-bind="text:Deloitte_Capability"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Javascript function:-

```
  function ClickAddMapping()
    {
        $('#SVRnew').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#SVRnew tbody tr').remove();
        _dtsvrnew = $('#SVRnew').DataTable({
            scrollY: '30vh',
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false,
            "scrollX": true

        });

        VMHome.LISTSVREASnew([]);
        var selectedevents = ko.computed(function () {
            return VMHome.EventMappingforsvr().filter(function (i) {
                return i.ISSELECTED() === true;
            });
        });

        var selectedsvr = ko.computed(function () {
            return VMHome.SVRList().filter(function (i) {
                return i.ISSELECTED() === true;
            });
        });


            for (var j = 0; j < selectedevents().length; j++)
            {
                for (var k = 0; k < selectedsvr().length; k++)
                {
                    VMHome.LISTSVREASnew().push(new EASSVRModel({ 'SVR': selectedsvr()[k].SVR(), 'DSVRID': selectedsvr()[k].DSVRID(), 'Deloitte_Capability': selectedsvr()[k].Deloitte_Capability(), 'EAS_UID': selectedevents()[j].EAS_UID(), 'DOMAIN': selectedevents()[j].DOMAIN(), 'SUB_DOMAIN': selectedevents()[j].SUB_DOMAIN(), 'EVENT_TYPE': selectedevents()[j].EVENT_TYPE(), 'EVENT_SUBTYPE': selectedevents()[j].EVENT_SUBTYPE(), 'EVENT_NAME': selectedevents()[j].EVENT_NAME() }));
                }
            }

        }
```

Even after destroying datatable, it doesn't update data.
Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

datatable with knockout won't work from the box. 
You can check out next references: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/31797/knockout-js-3-4-custom-binding-for-jquery-datatables-net, [Datatable data binding using knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707378/datatable-data-binding-using-knockoutjs)

In general case, you need to subscribe to changes of your array and then add (or remove) items from grid like this:

```
this.addItem = function (newItem) {
    if (dataTable && dataTable.row && newItem) {
        dataTable.row.add(newItem).draw(false);
    }
};
```

where datatable: `let dataTable = $('#yourTable').DataTable();`